# Keeping scrolling down until it located the respective Filter(Element?) and click it - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, pycharm, element

Hi im currently doing selenium Python. the scenario is this: im currently trying to find a certain "element" or let say Filter(since im doing selenium to online shop), for example i want to find a filter name: "LCD".
the  result is error. the problem is this LCD is out of the screen which means i need to scroll down until that filter appears or viewable in the screen then i can click it. the problem is i do not know the correct code or probably i coded it wrong. my code is this:

my browser will keep scrolling down(condition "except") until it find the element Filter i choose. the problem is it didnt click. yes it appeared in screen but it didnt clicked(which should be the condition "try").

```
while finding_click is False:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"' + filtchooseText + '")]').click()
        finding_click = True
    except:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(scroll))
        scroll = scroll + 20
```

i wonder what was wrong? i wonder what is the code for that if this is wrong? keep scrolling down until you find the respective element then click it...?

Software im using: Pycharm, Selenium

Answer (score 0):

if the browser is in full screen mode then the below code should work for you.

to maximize it :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("some URL")
```

and then to find filter and click on it use ActionChains :

```
   while True:
        try:
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"' + filtchooseText + '")]')).click().perform()
            break
        except:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(scroll))
            scroll = scroll + 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this

first import this

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

then use like this

```
while finding_click is False:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"' + filtchooseText + '")]').click()
            finding_click = True
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            sleep(randint(2, 3))
            continue
```